# Symfony SwiftMailer: Emails are only sent within AppBundle but not within other Bundles

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.3

I have separate bundles for the Frontend (FrontendBundle) and the Backend (AppBundle). I want to send emails in the controller methods of both bundles. The code I use to send the emails looks as follows:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setFrom('xxxxxxx')
    ->setTo('xxxxxxxx')
    ->setBody(
         $this->templating->render(
            '@AppBundle/emails/test.html.twig'
         ),
         'text/html'
     )
;
$this->mailer->send($message);
```

When I put this code in a controller method within AppBundle, it works flawlessly. However, when I put the code in a controller method within FrontendBundle, the emails are not sent and I do not get an error.

Hence, the code itself seems to work without problems. I suppose it could be a configuration problem, but I ran out of ideas where to look.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
```

parameters.yml

```
 parameters:
        mailer_transport: smtp
        mailer_host: xxxxxxxx
        mailer_user: xxxxxxxx
        mailer_password: xxxxxxxx
```

This might be also relevant: I set up virtual hosts so that AppBundle runs on app.localhost and FrontendBundle on localhost. This is reflected in the Message ID that is displayed in the Symfony Profiler (e.g., f4f2a2604asd5618d4caf892e5e4e5@app.localhost).

Comment: Did you try clear cache?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: I re-opened my answer with edits based on the new information you provided with multiple hosts.  Check it out and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at configuration [multiple mailers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers) since it appears you are having issues with having two different hosts:

**config.yml:**

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: app_mailer
    mailers:
        app_mailer:
            transport: '%mailer_transport%'
            host: '%mailer_host_app%'
            username: '%mailer_user%'
            password: '%mailer_password%'
        frontend_mailer:
            transport: '%mailer_transport%'
            host: '%mailer_host_frontend%'
            username: '%mailer_user%'
            password: '%mailer_password%'
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
parameters:
     mailer_transport: smtp
     mailer_host_app: app.localhost
     mailer_host_frontend: localhost
     mailer_user: xxxxxxxx
     mailer_password: xxxxxxxx
```

Then you'll need to inject the proper mailer based on which one you want in your service.  If you had access to the container directly this is what those services would look like:

```
// since app_mailer was the default, these are equivalent
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.app_mailer');
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');

$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.frontend_mailer');
```

Comment: Actually, the Symfony Profiler shows me that the Email is generated and I can even see the message body, so the mail is rendered correctly for both bundles.

Comment: So your profiler even says the email sent?  Doesn't sound like an issue with your code, sounds like an issue with the address you are sending to or some other sort of configuration issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I followed your advice in configuring the two mailers, but I still get the same result. Moreover, the "host" in the mailer config does refer to the smtp server of my provider and is the same for both mailers.

Comment: This is most definitely a configuration issue.  I have tons of problems getting mail to send with my own setups unless going through something like gmail or mailchimp or an outside provider; it seems like local operating systems are fickle about making sure headers match, not having spoofing, etc.  I'm sorry that my answer did not help and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: No problem!  Hopefully you figure it out - if so add your answer so we can all see what you did to resolve it.